# Java: Extending ArrayList Using Objects

Tags: java, object, arraylist, extends

I'm extending ArrayList (not implementing an interface) in Java. I get an error in the function:

```
 public void push(Object o) {
    add(o);
}
```

It says "The method add(E) in the type ArrayList< E > is not applicable for the arguments. How can I fix this?

Comment: Please show some more code on how you are extending the arraylist. I hope you  know what you are doing..:P

Comment: `public void push(E o) {` - But you have to ask the question why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me, I m not sure what you want to achieve with this.

```
public class MyList<E> extends ArrayList<E>{
     public void push(E o) {
            add(o);
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by [@shikjohari](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2595642/shikjohari) you need to specify how you extend the ArrayList.

The reason you get this error is because you are trying to push an `Object` to an ArrayList that is expecting to get something of type `E`. So you need to explicitly cast the `o` to type `E` in order for this to work (of course, you need to ensure that `o` is indeed of dynamic type `E` before you perform casting).

Assuming `E` is a class defined somewhere else (it does not represent a generic type here, otherwise, the compiler should give you another error - "E cannot be resolved to a type" instead of "The method add(E) in the type ArrayList< E > is not applicable for the arguments"), you should have something like the following:

```
// This class is defined somewhere in your package
class E {

}

public class YourClass extends ArrayList<E> {   
    public void push(Object o) {
        if (o instanceof E) {
            add((E) o);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I assume `E` is a class defined somewhere else, it does not represent a generic type in this case. Otherwise, the compiler should give you another error - "E cannot be resolved to a type"

Comment: Thanks for giving it a look. shikjohari solved the problem :)